# Parent table on add row also copies child table added rows instead of only first row

Tags: javascript, html

I have Html table for size, color and quantity means admin can select size and then across that size admin can select color and quantity of that size. if that size had more colors admin can add row to add more color for that size. And same case for the size if that dress has more size then admin can also add more row. I am doing this is nested table. Color and quantity is child table(nested).

Now when child table row is added it works fine but problem comes if i add new row for parent table it copies all the rows that are in first row's child table has instead of copy only first row and one more problem is that if i am in second row of parent table and i want to add or delete child table row then add new and delete button of child table in second row of Parent table will add or delete row of child table in first row of parent table.

```js
function dropdownlistsize(listindex1) {
  document.form1.size.options.length = 0;
  switch (listindex1) {

    case "MEN":
      document.form1.size.options[0] = new Option("Select Size", "");
      document.form1.size.options[1] = new Option("Small", "Small");
      document.form1.size.options[2] = new Option("Medium", "Medium");
      document.form1.size.options[3] = new Option("Large", "Large");
      document.form1.size.options[4] = new Option("X-Large", "X-Large");
      document.form1.size.options[5] = new Option("XX-Large", "XX-Large");
      break;

    case "WOMEN":
      document.form1.size.options[0] = new Option("Select Size", "");
      document.form1.size.options[1] = new Option("Small", "Small");
      document.form1.size.options[2] = new Option("Medium", "Medium");
      document.form1.size.options[3] = new Option("Large", "Large");
      document.form1.size.options[4] = new Option("X-Large", "X-Large");
      break;

    case "KIDS":
      document.form1.size.options[0] = new Option("Select Size", "");
      document.form1.size.options[1] = new Option("X-Small", "X-Small");
      document.form1.size.options[2] = new Option("Small", "Small");
      document.form1.size.options[3] = new Option("Medium", "Medium");
      document.form1.size.options[4] = new Option("Large", "Large");
      break;
  }
  return true;
}


function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 1) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }


    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}


function addRow1(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
}

th {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" class="contact-form" name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div><br/>
    <label>Gender<font color="red"></font></label>
    <select style="margin: -10px 40px 40px 75px;" name="dress_gender" id="dress_gender" onchange="javascript: dropdownlistsize(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required>
                  <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                  <option value="MEN">MEN</option>
                  <option value="WOMEN">WOMEN</option>
                  <option value="KIDS">KIDS</option>
                  </select>
  </div>

  <table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color & Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
        <td><select name="size[]" id="size" required="">
                  <option value="">Select Size</option></select></td>
        <td>

          <table style="margin-top: 20px;" id="dataTable1" width="400px" border="1">
            <thead>
              <th>&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;<b>Color&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="color[]" required="">
                    <option value="">Select Color</option>
                    <option value="Alizarin">Alizarin</option>   
                    <option value="Amaranth">Amaranth</option>   
                    <option value="Amber">Amber</option>    
                    <option value="Amethyst">Amethyst</option>   
                    <option value="Apricot">Apricot</option>    
                    <option value="Aqua">Aqua</option>   
                    <option value="Aquamarine">Aquamarine</option>   
                    <option value="Asparagus">Asparagus</option>      
                    <option value="Auburn">Auburn</option>   
                    <option value="Azure">Azure</option>    
                    <option value="Beige">Beige</option>  
                    <option value="Bistre">Bistre</option>   
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>   
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>   
                    <option value="Blue Green">Blue Green</option>   
                    <option value="Blue Violet">Blue Violet</option>    
                    <option value="Bondi Blue">Bondi Blue</option>   
                    <option value="Brass">Brass</option>    
                    <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>   
                    <option value="Brown">Brown</option>    
                    <option value="Buff">Buff</option>   
                    <option value="Burgundy">Burgundy</option>    
                    <option value="Burnt Orange">Burnt Orange</option>   
                    <option value="Burnt Sienna">Burnt Sienna</option>   
                    <option value="Burnt Umber">Burnt Umber</option>    
                    <option value="Camouflage Green">Camouflage Green</option>   
                    <option value="Caput Mortuum">Caput Mortuum</option>    
                    <option value="Cardinal">Cardinal</option>   
                    <option value="Carmine">Carmine</option>    
                    <option value="Carrot orange">Carrot orange</option>    
                    <option value="Celadon">Celadon</option>    
                    <option value="Cerise">Cerise</option>    
                    <option value="Cerulean">Cerulean</option>   
                    <option value="Champagne">Champagne</option>    
                    <option value="Charcoal">Charcoal</option>   
                    <option value="Chartreuse">Chartreuse</option>   
                    <option value="Cherry Blossom Pink">Cherry Blossom Pink</option>    
                    <option value="Chestnut">Chestnut</option>   
                    <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>    
                    <option value="Cinnabar">Cinnabar</option>   
                    <option value="Cinnamon">Cinnamon</option>   
                    <option value="Cobalt"> Cobalt</option>   
                    <option value="Copper">Copper</option>   
                    <option value="Coral">Coral</option>    
                    <option value="Corn">Corn</option>   
                    <option value="Cornflower">Cornflower</option>   
                    <option value="Cream">Cream</option>    
                    <option value="Crimson">Crimson</option>    
                    <option value="Cyan">Cyan</option>   
                    <option value="Dandelion">Dandelion</option>    
                    <option value="Denim">Denim</option>    
                    <option value="Ecru">Ecru</option>   
                    <option value="Emerald">Emerald</option>    
                    <option value="Eggplant">Eggplant</option>   
                    <option value="Falu red">Falu red</option>   
                    <option value="Fern green">Fern green</option>   
                    <option value="Firebrick">Firebrick</option>    
                    <option value="Flax">Flax</option>   
                    <option value="Forest green">Forest green</option>   
                    <option value="French Rose">French Rose</option>    
                    <option value="Fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>    
                    <option value="Gamboge">Gamboge</option>    
                    <option value="Gold">Gold</option>   
                    <option value="Goldenrod">Goldenrod</option>    
                    <option value="Green">Green</option>    
                    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>   
                    <option value="Han Purple">Han Purple</option>   
                    <option value="Harlequin">Harlequin</option>    
                    <option value="Heliotrope">Heliotrope</option>   
                    <option value="Hollywood Cerise">Hollywood Cerise</option>   
                    <option value="Indigo">Indigo</option>   
                    <option value="Ivory">Ivory</option>    
                    <option value="Jade">Jade</option>   
                    <option value="Kelly green">Kelly green</option>    
                    <option value="Khaki">Khaki</option>    
                    <option value="Lavender">Lavender</option>   
                    <option value="Lawn green">Lawn green</option>  
                    <option value="Lemon">Lemon</option>    
                    <option value="Lemon chiffon">Lemon chiffon</option>    
                    <option value="Lilac">Lilac</option>    
                    <option value="Lime">Lime</option>   
                    <option value="Lime green">Lime green</option>   
                    <option value="Linen">Linen</option>    
                    <option value="Magenta">Magenta</option>    
                    <option value="Magnolia">Magnolia</option>   
                    <option value="Malachite">Malachite</option>    
                    <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>   
                    <option value="Mauve">Mauve</option>    
                    <option value="Midnight Blue">Midnight Blue</option>    
                    <option value="Mint green">Mint green</option>   
                    <option value="Misty rose">Misty rose</option>   
                    <option value="Moss green">Moss green</option>   
                    <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>    
                    <option value="Myrtle">Myrtle</option>   
                    <option value="Navajo white">Navajo white</option>   
                    <option value="Navy Blue">Navy Blue</option>    
                    <option value="Ochre">Ochre</option>    
                    <option value="Office green">Office green</option>   
                    <option value="Olive">Olive</option>    
                    <option value="Olivine">Olivine</option>    
                    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>   
                    <option value="Orchid">Orchid</option>   
                    <option value="Papaya whip">Papaya whip</option>    
                    <option value="Peach">Peach</option>    
                    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>   
                    <option value="Periwinkle">Periwinkle</option>   
                    <option value="Persimmon">Persimmon</option>    
                    <option value="Pine Green">Pine Green</option>   
                    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>   
                    <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>   
                    <option value="Plum">Plum</option>   
                    <option value="Powder blue">Powder blue</option>    
                    <option value="Puce">Puce</option>   
                    <option value="Prussian blue">Prussian blue</option>    
                    <option value="Psychedelic purple">Psychedelic purple</option>   
                    <option value="Pumpkin">Pumpkin</option>    
                    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>   
                    <option value="Quartz Grey">Quartz Grey</option>    
                    <option value="Raw umber">Raw umber</option>    
                    <option value="Razzmatazz">Razzmatazz</option>   
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>    
                    <option value="Robin egg blue">Robin egg blue</option>   
                    <option value="Rose">Rose</option>   
                    <option value="Royal blue">Royal blue</option>   
                    <option value="Royal purple">Royal purple</option>   
                    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>   
                    <option value="Russet">Russet</option>   
                    <option value="Rust">Rust</option> 
                    <option value="Safety orange">Safety orange</option>    
                    <option value="Saffron">Saffron</option>    
                    <option value="Salmon">Salmon</option>   
                    <option value="Sandy brown">Sandy brown</option>    
                    <option value="Sangria">Sangria</option>    
                    <option value="Sapphire">Sapphire</option>   
                    <option value="Scarlet">Scarlet</option>    
                    <option value="School bus yellow">School bus yellow</option>    
                    <option value="Sea Green">Sea Green</option>    
                    <option value="Seashell">Seashell</option>   
                    <option value="Sepia">Sepia</option>    
                    <option value="Shamrock green">Shamrock green</option>   
                    <option value="Shocking Pink">Shocking Pink</option>    
                    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>   
                    <option value="Sky Blue">Sky Blue</option>   
                    <option value="Slate grey">Slate grey</option>   
                    <option value="Smalt">Smalt</option>    
                    <option value="Spring bud">Spring bud</option>   
                    <option value="Spring green">Spring green</option>   
                    <option value="Steel blue">Steel blue</option> 
                    <option value="Tan">Tan</option>    
                    <option value="Tangerine">Tangerine</option>    
                    <option value="Taupe">Taupe</option>    
                    <option value="Teal">Teal</option>   
                    <option value="Tenné">Tenné</option>    
                    <option value="Terra cotta">Terra cotta</option>    
                    <option value="Thistle">Thistle</option>    
                    <option value="Titanium White">Titanium White</option>   
                    <option value="Tomato">Tomato</option>   
                    <option value="Turquoise">Turquoise</option>    
                    <option value="Tyrian purple">Tyrian purple</option> 
                    <option value="Ultramarine">Ultramarine</option> 
                    <option value="Van Dyke Brown">Van Dyke Brown</option>   
                    <option value="Vermilion">Vermilion</option>    
                    <option value="Violet">Violet</option>   
                    <option value="Viridian">Viridian</option> 
                    <option value="Wheat">Wheat</option>    
                    <option value="White">White</option>    
                    <option value="Wisteria">Wisteria</option> 
                    <option value="Xanthic">Xanthic</option> 
                    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>   
                    <option value="Zucchini">Zucchini</option>
                  </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input style="width: 120px; height: 26px; " oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1" onchange="calculate();" min="1" max="1000" maxlength="4"
                  placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow1('dataTable1')" />
          <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow1('dataTable1')" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
  <br/><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: The paragraph with your problem is very hard to read.

Comment: @Sven The Surfer  i just edit it. also please run doe snippet to see demonstration of problem